# How to transform string to an integer 1 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  cust_id     desktop           laptop          accessories
  123         2020-02-22        2020-01-01      0
  234         2019-02-02        0               0
  211         2020-02-23        0               0
```

My desired dataframe is as follows

```
  cust_id     desktop           laptop          accessories
  123         1                 1               0
  234         1                 0               0
  211         1                 0               0
```

Wherever there is value apart from 0 has to be transformed to 1. All the columns are in datatype `object`

How to do this in pandas?

Comment: Where does the data come from? Maybe fixing upriver would be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df.update((df.loc[:,'desktop':].astype(str)!='0').astype(int))
df
   cust_id desktop laptop  accessories
0      123       1      1            0
1      234       1      0            0
2      211       1      0            0
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x != 0 else 0)
```

Output:

```
         desktop  laptop  accessories
cust_id                              
123            1       1            0
234            1       0            0
211            1       0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [47]: import numpy as np

In [48]: df.desktop = np.where(df.desktop.ne('0'), 1, 0)    
In [49]: df.laptop = np.where(df.laptop.ne('0'), 1, 0)  

In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
   cust_id  desktop  laptop  accessories
0      123        1       1            0
1      234        1       0            0
2      211        1       0            0
```

Comment: If he has twenty columns, is he forced to do this for each column without relying on a for loop?